# Saving information in my sql table depending on a select option value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, validation

I have a form with a select option, to select the level of andmin.
And I have the value "1" for "Super Admin" and the value of "2" for "Admin".

And I want to save this info "Super Admin" and "Admin" in my sql table, but I dont understand why Im saving the values "1" and "2" and not "Super Admin" or "Admin" as I wanted.

Do you see something wrong?

```
if(isset($_POST['sendForm']))
  {  
    if($f['admin_level'] == '1') { $f['admin_level'] == 'Super Admin'; }
    if($f['admin_level'] == '2') { $f['admin_level'] == 'Admin'; }
  }
```

```
      <label>
        <span>Select admin level:</span>
        <select name="admin_level">
        <option value="">Select admin level</option>
        <option value="1">Super Admin</option>
        <option value="2">Admin</option>                 
        </select>
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="sendForm"/>

</form>
```

Comment: post your complete script we cant work with just this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using == in your if statements for assignment. However this is a logical operator.

Change this:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendForm']))
{  
  if($f['admin_level'] == '1') { $f['admin_level'] == 'Super Admin'; }
  if($f['admin_level'] == '2') { $f['admin_level'] == 'Admin'; }
}
```

To:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendForm']))
{  
  if($f['admin_level'] == '1') { $f['admin_level'] = 'Super Admin'; }
  if($f['admin_level'] == '2') { $f['admin_level'] = 'Admin'; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! you are right! But in my example I have like you said and its not working. I just put thins wrong doing the translation!

Comment: Thank you, after all I had wrong in my example! It was really that the problem. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, in my language Admin have an accent like "správce". And in sql appears like " sprÃ¡vce". Do you know how to fix this accent problems with sql?

Comment: If you are having issues with accents, you're most likely course of action is to investigate the SQL Language collation settings. Something may not be playing nice with how the database stores your language.